# Error al usar ResultSet. Solo devuelve una sola fila

Tags: java, jdbc

He creado un programa que sirve para ver el contenido de una base de datos que contiene mas de 300 entradas. Pero solamente consigo la primera de ellas:

```
        public static Comics[] verTodo() throws SQLException 
         { 
                 int posicion = 0; 
                 String sentenciaSql = "SELECT * from comics.comicsbbdd"; 
  
                 Comics comic []= null; 
  
                 ResultSet rs = DBManager.getComic(sentenciaSql); 
  
                 try { 
                         if(rs.last()) { 
                                 comic = new Comics[(rs.getRow())]; 
                                 System.out.println(); 
                                 rs.isBeforeFirst(); 
  
                                 do 
                                 { 
                                         String nombre = rs.getString("nomComic"); 
                                         String numero = rs.getString("numComic"); 
                                         String variante = rs.getString("nomVariante"); 
                                         String firma = rs.getString("firma"); 
                                         String editorial = rs.getString("nomEditorial"); 
                                         String formato = rs.getString("formato"); 
                                         String procedencia = rs.getString("procedencia"); 
                                         String anioPubli = rs.getString("anioPubli"); 
                                         String guionista = rs.getString("nomGuionista"); 
                                         String dibujante = rs.getString("nomDibujante"); 
                                         comic[posicion] = new Comics(nombre,numero,variante,firma,editorial,formato,procedencia,anioPubli,guionista,dibujante); 
                                         posicion++; 
                                          
                                 } 
                                 while(rs.next()); 
                         } 
  
                 } 
                 catch(Exception ex) 
                 { 
                         System.out.println(); 
                 } 
                 return comic; 
         }
```

Todo esto usando `javaFX` y la base de datos es en `mysql`.
Muchas gracias por la ayuda.

EDIT

He conseguido que funcione, pero claramente el codigo esta feo, he intentado mejorarlo, pero cuando lo hago, deja de verse todo el contenido de la base de datos:

```
    public static Comics[] verTodo() throws SQLException
    {
        int posicion = 0;
        String sentenciaSql = "SELECT * from comics.comicsbbdd";

        Comics comic []= null;

        ResultSet rs = DBManager.getComic(sentenciaSql);

        try {
            if(rs.last()) {
                comic = new Comics[(rs.getRow())];
                rs.beforeFirst();

                if(rs.first())
                {
                    do
                    {
                        String nombre = rs.getString("nomComic");
                        String numero = rs.getString("numComic");
                        String variante = rs.getString("nomVariante");
                        String firma = rs.getString("firma");
                        String editorial = rs.getString("nomEditorial");
                        String formato = rs.getString("formato");
                        String procedencia = rs.getString("procedencia");
                        String anioPubli = rs.getString("anioPubli");
                        String guionista = rs.getString("nomGuionista");
                        String dibujante = rs.getString("nomDibujante");
                        comic[posicion] = new Comics(nombre,numero,variante,firma,editorial,formato,procedencia,anioPubli,guionista,dibujante);
                        System.out.println(comic[posicion].toString());
                        posicion++;
                    }
                    while(rs.next());
                }
                System.out.println(comic.length);
            }

        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            System.out.println();
        }
        return comic;
    }
```

Me gustaria dejarlo mas elegante, ya que en mi opinion creo que es una chapuza lo que hice para arreglarlo.
He tratado quitar el primer if, junto al "beforeFirst()", pero eso hace que ya no funcione correctamente.

Answer (score 0):

## Anotaciones

- ¿Estás seguro de que manejas bien el establecimiento y cierre de la conexión? Recuerda que por cuestiones de seguridad se recomienda no mantener la conexión a la base de datos abierta cuando no está en uso. Para evitar establecer la conexión varias veces puedes usar una pool de conexiones o un singleton pero con CUIDADO
- No es necesario usar [rs#last](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/ResultSet.html#last()) y [rs#first](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/ResultSet.html#first()) (de hecho se ve muy extraño y feo), simplemente crea un [ArrayList](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/ArrayList.html), si es estrictamente necesario retornar un arreglo, convierte el ArrayList en arreglo.
- Cambia el nombre de tu método "verTodo" ¿Qué estás viendo? es un nombre muy confuso, se recomienda que uses inglés pero si quieres mantenerlo en español puedes usar algo como "obtenerComics", pero sé más específico o luego traerá complicaciones
- Estás haciendo mal uso de throw Exception, nunca estás aventando la excepción, en el ejemplo mantuve el catch, pero decídete, o lo atrapas *`catch`* o lo avientas *`throw`*, te recomiendo estudiar cómo manejar los errores

```java
public static ArrayList<Comics> getAllComics() {
    String query = "SELECT * from comics.comicsbbdd";

    ArrayList<Comics> comics = new ArrayList<>();
    ResultSet rs = DBManager.getComic(query);

    try {

        while (rs.next()) {
            String nombre = rs.getString("nomComic");
            String numero = rs.getString("numComic");
            String variante = rs.getString("nomVariante");
            String firma = rs.getString("firma");
            String editorial = rs.getString("nomEditorial");
            String formato = rs.getString("formato");
            String procedencia = rs.getString("procedencia");
            String anioPubli = rs.getString("anioPubli");
            String guionista = rs.getString("nomGuionista");
            String dibujante = rs.getString("nomDibujante");
            comics.add(new Comics(nombre,numero,variante,firma,editorial,formato,procedencia,anioPubli,guionista,dibujante));
        }
    } catch(SQLException e) {
//          Sólo para debugging, borrar después
        System.err.println("Error en método getAllComics");
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(e.getStackTrace()));
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    System.out.println(comics.size());
    return comics;
}
```